# ISCC.exe not found in powershell

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

I have Powershell5 upon windows10:

```
> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  868
```

And Once I try to run ISCC.exe (Innosetup Client) I get the following error:

```
> ISCC.exe --help
ISCC.exe : The term 'ISCC.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. C
heck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ISCC.exe --help
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ISCC.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Make sure install folder of Inno Setup is stored in your `PATH` environment variable or define an alias: `Set-Alias iscc "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Inno Setup 6\ISCC.exe"`. Now you can write `iscc /?`.

Comment: I just put the `C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)\Inno Setup 6\ISCC.exe` Into path and works.